# ZSH autocomplete second argument

Tags: autocomplete, zsh, tab-completion

I'm on my $HOME directory, there is a foo.zip file.
I want to extract it into $HOME/work directory, which exists

I type unzip foo it expands the filename, I enter   but it doesn't expand the "w" to the "work" directory

How make this work ? In Bash this works out of the box.

Comment: What *exactly* did you type? My version of `unzip` expects the second argument to be the name of a file inside the archive, and that's what zsh completes. To extract to a different directory, I type `unzip foo.zip -d w`, and `zsh` does complete `w` into `work`.

Comment: @Gilles: Your comment should be an answer. The difference is that the Bash completion function for `unzip` is simple-minded and doesn't look at the contents of the archive or whether `-d` is present. The zsh completion for `unzip` is much more sophisticated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to preceed the exdir (the directory to expand into) with the '-d' switch.

Comment: And I need to go through and add some functionality to my Easy Extract function in bash.